# How can I access my table using Entity Framework from an endpoint?

Tags: c#

I have a small project in .NET that is using Entity Framework, and I followed this tutorial:
https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/asp-net-core-5-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api-aa59e80d02da and have that as a base.

I want to extend my project to support storing and image url and text, I have a table named `cms_posts` and the structure looks like this:

```
| postId | postImage | postTitle | postBody |
```

`postId` is an `int` and auto-increments, and the rest are just text columns.

My `ApplicationDbContext` looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<CreatePostModel> postModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<CreatePostModel>().ToTable("cms_posts");
    }
}
```

And the `CreatePostmodel`:

```
public class CreatePostModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post image URL is required!")]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post title is required!")]
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post body is required!")]
    public string PostBody { get; set; }
}
```

And I add it to the startup like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)));
```

And I can see my table `cms_posts` in the database with the correct columns and all.

The issue I'm currently facing is that I have an endpoint `/posts` and I want that endpoint to return all the rows from the `cms_posts` table.

But how can I pass the context to that table into my endpoint so I can get all the rows?

Comment: You've got your context wired up for DI so just add it to the controller's constructor and it will get injected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register a `DbContext` in the IoC Container, it's available for dependency injection in your classes.

Here is a sample controller how it can be done.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    
    public PostsController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    
    [HttpGet("posts")]
    public async Task<List<CreatePostModel>> GetPostsAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.postModels.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Possible improvements:

- It's a recommended practice in APIs to NOT return the entity models directly. Create a separate DTO class and convert the entities to DTOs before returning results from your API.
- Look into the repository/unit of work patterns.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**
Create model class for Posts.
The database annotations I prefer to set configuration in DbContext.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ExtendIdentity.Model

{
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post image URL is required!")]
        public string ImageURL { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post title is required!")]
        public string PostTitle { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post body is required!")]
        public string PostBody { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

**Step 2.**
Create configuration class for Post class. This is an example, I seed data for test purposes.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace ExtendIdentity.Model
{
    public class PostConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("cms_posts");

            builder.Property(e => e.PostId)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasColumnName("postId");
            
            builder.Property(e => e.PostTitle)
                .IsUnicode()
                .HasMaxLength(64)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("postTitle");
            
            builder.Property(e => e.PostBody)
                .IsUnicode()
                .HasMaxLength(8000)
                .IsRequired().HasColumnName("postBody");

            builder.Property(e => e.ImageURL)
                .IsUnicode()
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("postImage");

            builder.HasKey(e => e.PostId);

            //seed data for tests
            builder.HasData(new Post[]
            {
                new Post
                {
                    PostId = 1,
                    PostTitle = "Post 1",
                    PostBody = "Post 1 - Body",
                    ImageURL = "http://domain/post1.jpg"
                },

                new Post
                {
                    PostId = 2,
                    PostTitle = "Post 2",
                    PostBody = "Post 2 - Body",
                    ImageURL = "http://domain/post3.jpg"
                },

                new Post
                {
                    PostId = 3,
                    PostTitle = "Post 3",
                    PostBody = "Post 3 - Body",
                    ImageURL = "http://domain/post3.jpg"
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3.**
For ApplicationDbContext add contructor with options parameter, add a DbSet for Posts and apply configuration(PostConfiguration class) in OnModelCreating method.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ExtendIdentity.Model
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } = null!;
         
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new PostConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4.**
Add migration.

```
Add-Migration cms_post_added
```

**Step 5.**
Update the database with the new migration.

```
Update-Database
```

**Step 6.**
In the controller add ApplicationDbContext parameter to contructor. The context is created by dependency injection.

```
using ExtendIdentity.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ExtendIdentity.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<UsersController> _logger;

        public UsersController(ApplicationDbContext context, ILogger<UsersController> logger)
        {
            this._context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet("post")]
        public IEnumerable<Post> GetPosts() 
        {
            // You can create a DTO class instead of return model classes
            // Not opimized query.imagine that there are 1 million records and have to return them through the api. 
            //You have to optimize with a filter.
            return _context.Posts.ToList(); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Setp 7.**
Enjoy!
[image: output]